# When to use WeakReference?

Tags: java, weak-references

I understand what a Java WeakReference is. What I want to know is on which kind of concrete problems it's used normally as a solution. Are there any patterns that include them?

Comment: You can use it to keep some properties related to an object without preventing the deletion of that object.

Comment: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references (first link on Google)

Comment: Do not forget you have the stackoverflow wiki of the tag itself: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/weak-references/info

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy lol. I wrote that tag wiki, should have remembered and linked to it instead of doing an answer. :D

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231565/why-do-we-need-weak-reference-in-java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`WeakReference` and `SoftReference` are used when you want to keep something around in case you need it again - but you might not need it and if you do need it you can recreate it.

For example if you have a Cache of information you've fetched from a website, you don't want to constantly re-fetch it but if you need memory you can always drop something you haven't used for a while and get it back again if you do need it.

`SoftReferences` in particular are useful for this sort of caching as it tells the GarbageCollector not to get rid of the objects unless it really needs to free up the memory.

`WeakReference` on the other hand the GC can clean up as soon as it likes.

I've used them before combined with a factory pattern. Keep a `SoftReference` to objects when you create them in the factory. If they are asked for again then return the already-created object. If they don't exist or have been garbage collected then create them, return them, and keep a `SoftReference` inside the factory.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Yep, was already typing one :)

Comment: Solely relying on Weak/SoftReference for caching [is generally not a good idea as it may lead to poor performance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11232117/829571) - it's often better to use an explicit caching strategy.