# Is it possible to make sure that two identical objects don't exist in JVM?

Tags: java

Consider this database model:

```
Book
isbn primary key
title
```

In a RDBMS, the database makes sure that two identical rows don't exist for the above model.

Similarly, in Java consider this object model:

```
Book
- isbn: int
- title: String
+ Book(isbn)
```

Let's say we are creating a Book object:

```
Book b = new Book(123456);
```

Later, in some other part of the code we are creating again an identical Book object:

```
Book c = new Book(123456);
```

Can Java make sure that no two objects exist in the JVM heap if they are identical? Just like a RDBMS does?

Comment: keep a list. In the constructor, check if an object with those values exists in the list, if not, continue creation, if yes, throw an Exception. Some sort of factory could help as well

Comment: Never use a list for this when you can check identity using a Set or a Map.

Comment: Yes, create a factory for Book that manages the instances in a hash map

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in mechanism in Java that automatically does this for you. You *could* build something for this, but probably shouldn't. And if you do, then probably not in the way that you show in your question.

First: let's assume that these objects are immutable, so the problem is reduced to "let no two objects be constructed that have the same attributes". This is not a *necessary* restriction, but this way I can already demonstrate the issues with this approach.

The first issue is that it requires you to *keep track* of each `Book` instance in your program in a single central place. You *can* do that quite easily by having a collection that you fill when an object is constructed.

However, this basically builds a massive memory leak into your program because if nothing else hangs on to this `Book` object, that collection still will reference it, preventing it from being garbage collected.

You can work around that issue by using [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) object to hold on to your `Book` objects.

Next, if you want to avoid duplicates, you almost certainly want a way to fetch the "original" instance of a `Book` if you can't create a new one. You can't do that if you simply use the constructor, since the constructor can't "return another object", it will always create and return a new object.

So instead of `new Book(12345)` you want something like `BookFactory.getOrCreateBook(12345)`. That factory can then either fetch the existing `Book` object with the given id *or* create a new one, as required.

One way to make the memory leak issue easier to handle (and also to potentially allow multiple parallel sessions each with their *own* set of unique `Book` objects) is to make the `BookFactory` be a `BookSession`: i.e. you instantiate one and it keeps tracks of *its* books. Now that `BookSession` is the "root" of all Books and if it no longer gets referenced it (and all the books it created) can potentially be garbage collected.

All of this doesn't even get into thread safety which is solvable reasonably easily for immutable objects but can get quite convoluted if you want to allow modifications while still maintaining uniqueness.

A simple `BookSession` could look a little like this (note that I use a `record` for book only for brevity of this sample code, this would leave the constructor visible. In "real" code I'd use an equivalent normal class where the constructor isn't accessible to others):

```
record Book(int isbn, String title) {}

class BookSession {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Book> books = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Optional<Book> get(int isbn) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(books.get(isbn));
    }

    public Book getOrCreate(int isbn, String title) {
        return books.computeIfAbsent(isbn, (i) -> new Book(i, title));
    }
}
```

You can easily add other methods to the session (such as `findByTitle` or something like that).

And **if** you only ever want a single `BookSession` you could even have a `public static final BookSession BOOKS` somewhere, if you wanted (but at that point you have re-created the memory leak)

Comment: Good answer. Was added at the same time, so referred to it from mine, as the TS might have just wanted to see a basic factory method for some simpler domain.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of a JVM internals specific way of doing this, but it is not that hard to achieve the *basic* goal. Joachim Sauer's answer goes into depth on why this might not be the greatest idea without some additional forethought :)

If you forego of thread safety, the code is basically just about creating a private constructor and use a factory method that keeps tab on created objects.

Pseudo Java follows

```
public class Book {
  // potential memory leak, see Joachim Sauer's answer (WeakReference)
  Map<Book> created = new Map<>();
  // other internal fields follow

  // can only be invoked from factory method
  private Book(String isbn){ /* internals */ }

  public Book get(String isbn){
     if(created.has(isbn)) return created.get(isbn);
     var b = new Book(isbn);
     b.add(isbn, b);
     return b;
  }
}
```

Converting this to a thread safe implementation is just about adding some details * and is another question. Avoiding the potential memory leak means reading up on [weak references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729134/when-to-use-weakreference).

- i.e. locks (`synchronized`), mutexes, `Concurrent*`, `Atomic*`, etc

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the other answers is technically correct.

They will often work, but in situations where multiple [ClassLoaders](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) are in play they will both fail.

Any object instance can ever only be unique within the context of a specific ClassLoader, thus 2 instances of the same Book can exist, even if you guard against multiples being created within a specific ClassLoader.

Usually this won't be a problem as many (especially simpler) programs will never have to deal with multiple ClassLoaders existing at the same time.

There is btw no real way to protect against this.

Comment: Under the rules of the JVM two different classloaders loading the same .class file doesn't result in the same class. Therefore I'd argue that `new Book(1234)` loaded from a different classloader than the other `new Book(1234)` are *not* in fact "identical objects".

Comment: @JoachimSauer they are functionally identical in that they (are supposed to) represent the same data, which is identical in the way OP (and indeed most people) understands them to be. The main (if not only) reason to enforce something only being loaded once is to prevent data clashes where one instance changes and another doesn't.

Comment: Oh, I agree that what you are describing is often unintentional, usually very confusing and tricky to investigate. But I don't think it's a frequent enough problem to warrant a "you can't do this" answer in any practical sense.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it's definitely a corner case, but one I've run into several times over the last few years migrating legacy systems between application servers (which are notorious for having mutually incompatible classloader systems).