# Soft vs Weak References

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalizer

I have a question on `SoftReference`s `WeakReference`s in Java.

What i know is:

GC uses algorithms to decide whether or not to reclaim a softly reachable object, but always reclaims a weakly reachable object.

Does that mean GC never runs the `finalize()` method on `WeakReferences`?

Thanks

Comment: Try this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299659/what-is-the-difference-between-a-soft-reference-and-a-weak-reference-in-java>

Comment: You should not assume `finalize()` methods will _ever_ be called under any circumstances -- indeed, you should avoid their use at all.  See Effective Java item 7.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: But, the document I refereed in my answer saying, finalze() must be called. Isn't it contradictory?

Comment: EJ quote: "One shortcoming of finalizers is that there is no guarantee they’ll be executed promptly [JLS, 12.6]. It can take arbitrarily long between the time that an object becomes unreachable and the time that its finalizer is executed. This means that
you should never do anything time-critical in a finalizer."  To be sure, I didn't make that as clear as I could have...but honestly, using `finalize()` in the first place remains a terrible code smell.

Answer (score 2):

As per [The Truth About Garbage Collection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html)

> If a class defines a finalizer, then any instance of that class must
>   have the finalizer called prior to deallocation. This means that
>   deallocation is delayed by the inclusion of a finalizer.

Based on this my understanding is, irrespective of Week/Soft, if finalize defined, it will be called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow your line of reasoning, but the finalizer is definitely always called. As soon as an object becomes finalizable, all soft/weak references to it will be cleared. So the refs can be observed as `null` **before** finalization.