# Finalize() method ignoring the object in a map/list?

Tags: java

Is it possible for the `finalize()` method of an `Object` to be called despite the `Object` being present within a `List` or `Map`. If not, how would it be possible to detect when an `Object` is no longer accessible by anything except only having a presence in the `List`/`Map`.

The reason behind this is that I have a map which has a key of `UUID` which is the unique ID for the `Object`'s as the `Map`'s value. I need to know when the "value" objects of the map are no longer accessible so I can clear space as there will be a lot of objects, but I also need to have them within the map until they are no longer accessible anywhere else so I can retrieve them via their `UUID` when required.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all if you have

```
Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key,value);
```

and map is still referenced, then value is still referenced (via the map). So it won't get garbage collected.

If you want for value to be garbage collected you might want to consider reading about WeakReference [What is the difference between a soft reference and a weak reference in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299659/what-is-the-difference-between-a-soft-reference-and-a-weak-reference-in-java);

This way you can have

```
Map<K,WeakReference<V>> map = ...
map.put(key, new WeakReference<V>(v));
```

This way you can get the value using its `UUID`, simply by `map.get(key)`, but the value can also be garbage collected, and you can check if it has by

```
if (map.get(key).get()==null){
   //object was garbage collected
}
```

However, notice that if your value object is still referenced from another reference, it won't be garbage collected. So hope this help.

If your purpose is to implement a cache that makes sure that you don't use to much information, you might want to look at Guava's cache. Which has a memory bound, if you want or/and expiration time for objects.  http://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache

Comment: Exactly the type of thing I was looking for. Thank you!