# Extension fields in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

It's easy to write extension methods in Kotlin:

```
class A { }
class B {
    fun A.newFunction() { ... }
}
```

But is there some way to create extension variable? Like:

```
class B {
    var A.someCounter: Int = 0
}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

No - the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) explains this:

> Extensions do not actually modify classes they extend. By defining an extension, you do not insert new members into a class, but merely make new functions callable with the dot-notation on instances of this class.

and

> Note that, since extensions do not actually insert members into classes, there’s no efficient way for an extension property to have a backing field. This is why initializers are not allowed for extension properties. Their behavior can only be defined by explicitly providing getters/setters.

Thinking about extension functions/properties as just syntactic sugar for calling a static function and passing in a value hopefully makes this clear.

However, if you *really, really* want to do something like this...

As stated above regarding efficiency, an additional backing field added directly to the class is the best way to store data non-derivable from existing non-private members from the class. However, if you don't control the implementation of the class and are dead-set on creating a new property that can store new data, it *can* be done in a way that is not abysmally *inefficient* by using separate external tables.  Use a separate map that keys on object instances of this class with values that map directly to the value you want to add then define an extension getter and/or setter for this property which uses your external table to store the data associated with each instance.

```
val externalMap = mutableMapOf<ExistingClass, Int>()

var ExistingClass.newExtensionProperty : Int
    get() = externalMap[this] ?: 0
    set(value:Int) { externalMap[this] = value }
```

The additional map lookups will cost you - and you need to consider memory leaks, or using appropriately GC-aware types, but it does work.

Comment: @AndrewOlson: Please don't add large comments like this that add significantly to the meaning in a post. (Summarising comments for example is fine, but just adding a load of stuff that wasn't previously mentioned isn't good.) I was surprised the edit was accepted at all, to be honest. It would have been better to add a comment indicating what else you'd like to see in the answer.

Comment: Additional map lookups are not that expensive for most uses, however the code shown will stop garbage collection for `ExistingClass` (all instances in the `externalMap` can never be garbage-collected). This is major memory leak, and should never be in an accepted answer. Using a `WeakReference` or `WeakHashMap` would be a step in the right direction (but not multiplatform).

Answer (score 92):

You can create an extension property with overridden getter and setter:

```
var A.someProperty: Int
  get() = /* return something */
  set(value) { /* do something */ }
```

But you cannot create an extension property with a backing field because you cannot add a field to an existing class.

Comment: What is the purpose of extension properties? Seems they are only there to confuse...?

Comment: @JohnyTex, they are useful to add properties to external classes (i.e. libraries), where you cannot modify them internally.

Answer (score 25):

There's [no way to add extension properties with backing fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties) to classes, because extensions [do not actually modify a class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically).

You can only define an extension property with custom getter (and setter for `var`) or a [delegated property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

---

However, if you need to define an extension property which *would behave as if it had* a backing field, delegated properties come in handy.
The idea is to create a property delegate that would store the *object-to-value* mapping:

- using the identity, not `equals()`/`hashCode()`, to actually store values for each object, like `IdentityHashMap` does;
- not preventing the *key* objects from being garbage collected (using [weak references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299659/what-is-the-difference-between-a-soft-reference-and-a-weak-reference-in-java)), like `WeakHashMap` does.

Unfortunately, there is no `WeakIdentityHashMap` in JDK, so you have to implement your own (or take a [complete implementation](http://www.grepcode.com/file_/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-search/3.3.0.CR2/org/hibernate/search/util/WeakIdentityHashMap.java/?v=source)).

Then, based on this mapping you can create a delegate class satisfying the [property delegates requirements](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#property-delegate-requirements). Here's an example non-thread-safe implementation:

```
class FieldProperty<R, T : Any>(
    val initializer: (R) -> T = { throw IllegalStateException("Not initialized.") }
) {    
    private val map = WeakIdentityHashMap<R, T>()

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T =
            map[thisRef] ?: setValue(thisRef, property, initializer(thisRef))

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>, value: T): T {
        map[thisRef] = value
        return value
    }
}
```

---

Usage example:

```
var Int.tag: String by FieldProperty { "$it" }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = 0
    println(x.tag) // 0

    val z = 1
    println(z.tag) // 1
    x.tag = "my tag"
    z.tag = x.tag
    println(z.tag) // my tag
}
```

When defined inside a class, the mapping can be stored independently for instances of the class or in a shared delegate object:

```
private val bATag = FieldProperty<Int, String> { "$it" }

class B() {
    var A.someCounter: Int by FieldProperty { 0 } // independent for each instance of B
    var A.tag: String by bATag // shared between the instances, but usable only inside B
}
```

Also, please note that identity [is not guaranteed](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation) for Java's primitive types due to boxing.

And I suspect the performance of this solution to be significantly worse than that of regular fields, most probably close to normal `Map`, but that needs further testing.

For nullable properties support and thread-safe implementation please refer to [here](https://github.com/h0tk3y/kotlin-fun/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/github/h0tk3y/kotlinFun/FieldProperty.kt).

Comment: this is a very nice creative hack. You could add a licence file to the github. Thanks!

Comment: What's a `WeakIdentityHashMap`?

Comment: This is an implementaiton of an object-to-value mapping that uses the identity, not `equals()`/`hashCode()`, and does not prevent an object from being deleted when it is no more reachable through other references. There's no more built-in implementation of such a mapping. The link to a third-party implementation that I posted seems to be broken now. Here's another link: https://github.com/archnetltd/castafioreframework/blob/master/casta-dependencies/src/hibernate-source/org/hibernate/search/util/WeakIdentityHashMap.java

Comment: Brilliant for testing purposes +1

Answer (score 12):

You can't add a field, but you can add a property, that delegates to other properties/methods of the object to implement its accessor(s). For example suppose you want to add a `secondsSinceEpoch` property to the `java.util.Date` class, you can write

```
var Date.secondsSinceEpoch: Long 
    get() = this.time / 1000
    set(value) {
        this.time = value * 1000
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending View you can do it quite easily like this...
This is example how I create some my custom class Event property in EditText class extension:

Define id for key :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="EditTextEventOnClearTagKey" type="id" />
</resources>
```

Define one reusable extension like this:

```
fun <T : Any> View.tagProperty(@IdRes key: Int, onCreate: () -> T): T {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    var value = getTag(key) as? T
    if (value.isNull) {
        value = onCreate()
        setTag(key, value)
    }
    return value!!
}
```

Use it in wherever View extension you need:

```
val EditText.eventClear get() = tagProperty(R.id.EditTextEventOnClearTagKey) { event<Unit>() }
```

Comment: Now it's hard to believe that this question was asked at a time when no one even thought that Kotlin would become the official language for Android :)