# how does weakhashmap work?

Tags: java, hashmap

As in how does weakhashmap understand that a reference to one of its key is obsolete now especially if the key is a String which is pooled?

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154724/when-would-you-use-a-weakhashmap-or-a-weakreference

Answer (score 3):

You must not use String literals with WeakHashMap (well you can but there would be no point in it):

```
String myKey = "somekey";
```

instead you must use:

```
String myKey = new String("somekey");
```

In the latter case String is not pooled.

Comment: Those examples are the same. A String literal is a String. At some stage after any String has no (strong/normal) references to it, it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Not quite the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning

Answer (score 1):

The word 'obsolete' is imprecise. The condition in question is 'garbage-collected'. A value is removed from the WeakHashMap when and if the key is garbage-collected. Period.