# understanding the difference between java.lang.String s = new String("hello") and String hold = "hello"

Tags: java, android

I came across this code and got a bit confused

```
java.lang.String s = new String("hello");
```

Im not sure what variable s is being initialized as java.lang.String , and what is the purpose of this vs String hold = "hello".  I tried to look through some some documentation but could not find anything.

Comment: When you call `new` you are string a new object, so you are creating a copy of the string literal.

Answer (score 5):

This is really bad programming style

```
java.lang.String s = new String("hello");
```

Remember that all classes in `java.lang` are imported automatically. If you have a class called `String` in the same package, it will also be imported but shadow the `java.lang.String` class. That might be a reason to fully qualify the type like

```
java.lang.String s;
```

But in this case, you could only ever assign a `java.lang.String` reference to it since that class is `final` and therefore cannot be extended. The conventional thing to do would be

```
java.lang.String s = new java.lang.String("hello");
```

If you were asking about

```
java.lang.String s = new String("hello");
```

vs

```
java.lang.String s = "hello";
```

then check out the other answers or the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Ok you need to know about constants pool (String literal pool)

When you do

```
String s = "hello";
```

you are actually setting up the variable in the constant pool

where as when you do

```
String s = new String("hello");
```

it creates a separate object in the constant pool.

read more about it here

> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html

Comment: Note that `"hello"` will still be put in the constant pool regardless of which you do.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this:

```
String s = "hello";
```

is better than doing this:

```
String s = new String("hello");
```

The second method creates a string object when you do `"hello"`, passes it to the `String` constructor, and then creates *another* identical `String` object. The first method only creates one object.

Comment: 2 objects? that is a bit confusing... can you furture explain

Comment: The literal creates the first "hello" string, then the String constructor copies that string (Java strings are immutable), and the original is thrown away. There is a chance that all of this may be optimized away, but it is still pretty bad style.

Comment: @user2980837 The String constructor `public String(String original)` is called a _copy_ _constructor_ because it creates a copy of the string passed to it. See the link that dkatzel posted in a comment on your original question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you must look about is the immutable feature of String in java.
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-create-immutable-class-object-java-example-tutorial.html

String hold = "hello" uses the immutable nature of the string. So when you do,

```
    String hold2 = "hello"
```

both hold and hold2 refer to the same instance of "hello" string from the string pool. It means both refer to the same memory location.
But with

```
   String hold2 = new String("hello");
```

there is a new string "hello" at a new location and hold and hold2 objects refer to different memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should know is that Strings in java are immutable read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java). Next when you do `String s = "hello"` behind the scene what happens is that compiler looks into the `String Pool` (a place where strings are saved in java) and checks if there is a `hello` string already there. If it is, it points reference `s` to same string object and returns(Read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning)). Now if you do `String hold2 = new String("hello");` none of the above mentioned things happens. Even if you have `hello` string in String Pool it would still create a new string `hello` and point reference `hold2` to it.