# Understanding LCS using backtracking

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

I am trying to understand backtracking. 
For that I started with the following link -
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithms/Backtracking

It has explained LCS. I understand dynamic programming solution will be faster, but I am taking one step at a time. Is the pseudo code they have provided, correct?
For this : 
        String[] a = {"The", "great", "square", "has", "a", "same", "no", "corners"};
        String[] b = {"The", "great", "image", "has", "no", "a", "same", "form"};

it also prints "no".

This is my attempt, can someone please improve / correct it.

```
public ArrayList<String> getLongestCommonSubsequence(String[] a , String[] b, ArrayList<String> output)
{
    if(a.length == 0 || b.length == 0)
        return output;

    if(a[0]==b[0])
    {   
        output.add(a[0]);
        getLongestCommonSubsequence(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length), Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, b.length), output);
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<String> discardA = getLongestCommonSubsequence(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length), b, new ArrayList<String>());
        ArrayList<String> discardB = getLongestCommonSubsequence(a, Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, b.length), new ArrayList<String>());

        if(discardA.size() > discardB.size())
            output = discardA;
        if(discardB.size() > discardA.size())
            output = discardB;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Updated method with the suggestion from @David Eisenstat - 
Problem 1 - It still prints out "no"
Problem 2 - It gives out redundant values still. I think that's a side effect of using backtracking.

```
public ArrayList<String> getLongestCommonSubsequence(String[] a , String[] b, ArrayList<String> output)
{
    if(a.length == 0 || b.length == 0)
        return output;

    if(a[0].equals(b[0]))
    {   
        output.add(a[0]);
        getLongestCommonSubsequence(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length), Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, b.length), output);
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<String> discardA = getLongestCommonSubsequence(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length), b, output);
        ArrayList<String> discardB = getLongestCommonSubsequence(a, Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, b.length), output);

        if(discardA.size() > discardB.size())
            output.addAll(discardA);
        else if(discardB.size() > discardA.size())
            output.addAll(discardB);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run afoul of the distinction between variables and their values. The true branch of the `if` statement assumes that `getLongestCommonSubsequence` will leave its output in the specific `ArrayList` passed as an argument. The false branch, on the other hand, allocates two new `ArrayList`s and leaves the output in one or the other instead of the requested storage location. Instead of `output = discardA;` you need to do `output.addAll(discardA);`, so that the items are copied to the correct list (and likewise for `discardB`). Also, the second `if` there should be an `else`, so that exactly one `addAll` is performed.

Additionally, you should be using `a[0].equals(b[0])` instead of `a[0] == b[0]`, though that won't cause a bug as long as your test strings are [interned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning).

EDIT: Here's what I had in mind:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LCS {
    static void getLongestCommonSubsequence(String[] a, String[] b, List<String> output) {
        if (a.length == 0 || b.length == 0) {
        } else if (a[0].equals(b[0])) {
            output.add(a[0]);
            getLongestCommonSubsequence(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length), Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, b.length), output);
        } else {
            List<String> discardA = new ArrayList<String>();
            getLongestCommonSubsequence(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length), b, discardA);
            List<String> discardB = new ArrayList<String>();
            getLongestCommonSubsequence(a, Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, b.length), discardB);
            if (discardA.size() >= discardB.size()) {
                output.addAll(discardA);
            } else {
                output.addAll(discardB);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"The", "great", "square", "has", "a", "same", "no", "corners"};
        String[] b = {"The", "great", "image", "has", "no", "a", "same", "form"};
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        getLongestCommonSubsequence(a, b, output);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @DavidEisenstat, Thanks for replying. I updated the original post with your suggestions. Actually the addAll, is what I had done earlier, but it didn't work with that. So, I removed it to follow what was suggested in the pseudo code. It still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @ND27 You made a couple more tweaks that I hadn't intended -- it's still necessary to run the recursive calls into scratch lists. I pasted my version of the LCS code into my answer.