# How can I command back to top in `do while` loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm getting confused with this `do while` statement. I want to make if the user input `y` then it will loop back to `do` loop. I'm not sure how to command back to `do` loop since `C++` you can use `goto`keyword if I'm not mistaken.

```
do
    {
    System.out.print( "\nPlease Make A Choice :");
    input = stdin.readLine();
    x = Integer.parseInt(input);

    if (x == 1)     
        CalculateCircleArea.GetRadius();    
    else if (x == 2)
        CalculateRectangleArea.GetLengthAndHeight();
    else if (x == 3) 
        CalculateTriangleArea.GetHeightBaseAndBaseLength();
    else

    System.out.print("\t      WRONG INPUT");
    String input2;
    String abc = "\n\tDO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE?";
    String abc2 = "\n\t   PLEASE CHOOSE (Y/N):";
    String abc3 = abc.concat(abc2);
    System.out.print(abc3);
    input2 = stdin.readLine();  
    }while (choice == 'y');
```

Comment: If the condition is satisfied, it will iterate again, there is no need for a `goto` statement (same in c++)

Comment: Look at my answer it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Btw, you never assign anything to your `choice` variable in the body of the loop

Comment: What type of variable is `choice`? String? char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use like:

```
while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

instead of == this is not used to compare strings.

Also I don't see choice being set you may want input2 instead of choice?

```
while(input2.equalsIgnoreCase("y")
```

Comment: @brso05 It's works... Thank you very much. You help me a lot sir.. :) I will make your answer as my reference.. thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **continue** statement to start a new iteration of the loop.

```
do{
    ...
    continue;    // Stops the current loop and continues to the next iteration.
    ...
}while(...);
```

Also, I can offer some improvements to the code.

Use this

```
x = stdin.nextInt();
```

Instead of

```
input = stdin.nextLine();
x = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

`Scanner.nextInt()` will return the next integer it finds and is more efficient than reading in a String and converting it to an `int`. Using your current configuration is useful, however, when checking for input errors by using a try-catch block.

Use

```
System.out.print("\n\tDO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE? \n\t    PLEASE CHOOSE (Y/N)");
```

Instead of

```
String abc = "\n\tDO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE?";
String abc2 = "\n\t   PLEASE CHOOSE (Y/N):";
String abc3 = abc.concat(abc2);
System.out.print(abc3);
```

The former just makes sense and is more efficient, as you don't have to concatenate the Strings etc.

Also, `choice` doesn't seem to be declared or used anywhere. Are you sure that you aren't supposed to be using `input2`? If so, use the `String.equalsIgnoreCase("")` method instead of `==`, as `==` compares the object reference and not value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the user input into the right variable :

```
//...
  input2 = stdin.readLine();  
}while (choice == 'y');
```

Replaced by

```
//...
  choice = stdin.readLine();  
}while ("y".equals(choice));
```

Comment: Unless `choice`, as it would seem, was declared as a `char`.

Comment: True, but it look's like Edie like to call readLine, witch return a String

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the condition be like this?

```
    input2 = stdin.readLine();  
}
while (input2.equals("y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `choice` as `String` just to make your solution easy.

```
do{
    //.. 
    }while (choice == "y");
```

this code will be right if `choice` is  [interned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning) otherwise its good to use `equals()` method to compare string.

```
do{
    //...
    input2 = stdin.readLine();  
}
while (input2.equals("y"));
```

For more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Comment: @DavidConrad `input2` is a `String`.

Comment: yeah that's why I mentioned that I used choice as String.