# About String object creation

Tags: java, string

I am bit confused about string object creation. Can someone tell me, how many String objects get created in below 2 cases?

1)

```
String s = new String("abc");
s = s + "xyz";
```

2)

```
String s = new String("abc");
String s1 = "xyz";
```

Answer (score 5):

First case:

```
String s = new String("abc");
s = s + "xyz";
```

You have:

- `"abc"` is a string literal and is [interned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning) => one string instance
- `String s = new String("abc")` creates another string `"abc"` that is stored in the heap => another string instance;
- in `s = s + "xyz";` you have `"xyz"` as one string literal which is interned and another string on the heap is built with the concatenated value `"abcxy"` which is another string.

You have 4 strings created in total with the old value of `s` being discarded. You remain with the `"abc"` and `"xyz"` interned strings and string `"abcxyz"` which is stored in `s`.

Second case:

```
String s = new String("abc");
String s1 = "xyz";
```

You have:

- `"abc"` is a string literal and is interned => one instance
- `String s = new String("abc")` creates another string `"abc"` that is stored in the heap => another instance
- `String s1 = "xyz";` you have `"xyz"` as one string literal which is interned and `s1` points to it.

You have 3 strings created in total. You remain with two interned strings `"abc"` and `"xyz"`, another `"abc"` stored in the heap and referred by `s` while `s1` points to the interned `"xyz"`.

You might also have a look at this for some basic explanations: [The SCJP Tip Line: Strings, Literally](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html)

Answer (score 0):

After the execution of 1) you have one String object, after 2) you have two.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just want to know, is there any other ways by which  we can create a String object apart from above two.

Comment: String myStr = "This is my String";

Comment: This is same as my 2nd option. Do we have any 3rd scenario or case in which, an String object will be creats

Comment: Sorry i read wrong. I can not see any other ways. It would be like this.

String str = new String();
str = "Some text";

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Strings in Java are immutable, so every instance of modification or concatenation creates new String objects.