# Is an attribute String an object?

Tags: java, string

I am a little confused, I learned that `String`s are objects, therefore to compare them  you should use `String#equals`.

My question is: if I have a `String` as an attribute, is it an object?

To clarify my question:

```
Class A {
    public String nom; 
    A(nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
 }
```

... and in the main method:

```
 A a = new A("Sara");
 A b = new A("Youssef");
 A c = new A("Sara");

 a.nom == b.nom; ==> false
 a.nom == c.nom; ==> true
```

Therefore, is the comparison of `String`s' values more like c++, i.e. not about their references?

Comment: A String is an object regardless of where it is defined. Class level, method level, etc.. Your code won't compile by the way because you need to declare the parameter type of your constructor `A(String nom)`

Comment: That main function is probably faulty. You should not compare Strings in Java using `==` (you could, the compiler won't complain, but most likely it won't work properly).

Comment: @Yoda not sure this is a real duplicate. More like a counter-example, where the `==` operator returns `true` arbitrarily in my opinion. I.e. OP seems aware of the requirement to use `equals` for `String` comparison.

Comment: More likely  duplicate of [What is the difference between “text” and new String(“text”)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3052442/5037042)

Comment: By the way the syntax is correct and it did compile for that reason i asked

Comment: There is plenty of info on this in the canonical string compare Q&A. If it's still not clear, highlight a specific remark you have.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your constructor assigns its argument value to the instance variable `nom`...

The fact that `a.nom == c.nom` is arbitrary and due to the fact that literal `"Sara"` has been interned (or cached).

This doesn't mean you should ever expect consistent results when comparing `String`s other than with the `equals` method.

Comment: Thank u for the reply would you please clarify this part "The fact that a.nom == c.nom is arbitrary and due to the fact that literal "Sara" has been interned (or cached)."

Comment: @BadrMohamed you can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning) SO question about Java `String` interning (and its top-rated answer) for more information.

Comment: Last question : when you use Assignment operator this.nom = nom;
is it like nom=new String("nom")
or nom="nom"

Comment: More like the latter: the idiom assigns as a value to this nom the reference of given argument nom.