# String equals Evaluate

Tags: java, string, equals

I was in an interview and got a question as below:

```
String s = "abcde5";
String s1 ="abcde"+"5";
System.out.println(s==s1);
System.out.println(s.equals(s1));
String s4 = "abcd5";
String s3 = "abcd"+s4.length();
System.out.println(s3);
System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));
System.out.println(s3==s4);
```

I thought that the output will always yield false for "==" as using the + operator will create a new string same as doing the s4.length. but the expected answer is different. Can anyone please let me know why s==s1 gives true, and s3==s4 yields false.

expected answer is:
true
true
abcd5
true
false

Comment: This is not about string interning. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s==s1` yields `true` because `"abcde"+"5"` is a constant expression, i.e. an expression composed of string literals and concatenations. All Java compilers *must* treat them as a single literal, i.e. as if the `+` were not there.

Java language standard carefully makes an exception for compile-time constant string expressions when explaining new object creation on string concatenation:

> A new class instance is implicitly created when the string concatenation operator `+` (§15.18.1) is used in a non-constant (§15.28) expression, resulting in a new object of type `String` (§4.3.3).

Expression `"abcd"+s4.length()`, on the other hand, is not a constant expression. That is why a new object is created for it, causing `s3==s4` to yield `false`.

Comment: I read this here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning?noredirect=1&lq=1 that   `System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+lo)) + " ");` where  `static String hello = "Hello";` and  `String lo = "lo";` this will return false, because concatenating "lo" is not a constant expression?

Comment: @Sumitsagar Yes, `lo` is not a string literal. The example above it, i.e. `hello == ("Hel"+"lo")` produces `true`.

Comment: So anything other than concatenating string literals "==" will always yield false?and can you please tell what is (§4.3.3) symbol? thank you.

Comment: @Sumitsagar No, other constant expressions are OK (e.g. `"23"=="2"+3`, [demo](http://ideone.com/d2QlOR)). § is a reference to [Java Language Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jls-7-mr3-fullv-oth-JSpec/JLS-JavaSE7-Full.pdf?AuthParam=1483778786_5d50cae8ca7acf382d2d11c294941486).

Comment: I tried a few more.. like `s==s1+5` will yield false. or `s==s1+a` //where int `a=5`. and `s==(sn+"5")` will give false too, because compiler has to resolve their values at compile time? but `s=="abcde" +5` will give true,  because in simple terms the compiler doesn't have to evaluate the variable.

Comment: @Sumitsagar Please read section §4.3.3 of the language spec, it should give you clarity on the difference between constant expressions and non-constant expressions.