# What is going on with equality in JShell/Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I've been using JShell a bit just to test it out, and today I came across quite the interesting bit of behavior.

```
jshell> String a = "A"
a ==> "A"

jshell> String b = "A"
b ==> "A"

jshell> a == b
$4 ==> true

jshell> "A" == "A"
$5 ==> true
```

I was first wondering if this was a feature of Java 9, and I checked it out by compiling and running this program with Java 9

```
public class Equus {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String a = "A";
        String b = "A";
        System.out.println("a == b");
        System.out.println(a == b);
        System.out.println("\"A\" == \"A\"");
        System.out.println("A" == "A");
    }
}
```

And interestingly enough I got

> ```
> a == b 
> true 
> "A" == "A" 
> true
> ```

As my output as well. What's going on here? Why are `a` and `b` equal to each other and why is `"A" == "A"` true?

Comment: This is called _interning_, and is something the compiler does to optimize itself. Instead of creating a duplicate String object for the new _A_, it uses the one it already has. [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning).

Comment: Is there some switch to prevent Java from interning strings without an explicit call to `String#intern`?

Comment: You need to use `.equals()` to check whether or not the _Objects_ are equal, you are just checking the reference.

Comment: @MattClark I know. I was wondering why they were the same reference.

Comment: This is Java’s behavior since the very first version. Why should `"A" == "A"` ever be `false`?

Comment: this has nothing to do with java-9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why shouldn't it be? This behaviour is exhibited in previous Java versions as well - String literals are interned.

As you know, `==` checks for reference equality - the two variables have the same memory address. When a String is interned, all references of that string point to the intern pool and thus will be equal using `==`.

Comment: This furthermore explains why if I do `new String("A")` instead of `"A"` this doesn't work.

Comment: @Eli Sadoff: note that the objects created via `new String("A")` and `"A"` will still refer to the same array internally…

Comment: @Holger They're both `{'A', '\0'}`, no?

Comment: @Eli Sadoff: no, Java strings are never zero terminated. But I’m not referring to the array’s content anyway. I wanted to emphasize that they are pointing to the same array instance. So within the `String` class, `new String("A").value == "A".value` would be `true`.

Comment: @Holger Oh. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add this demonstration alongside Sinkingpoint's fine answer.
It's not safe to use `==` on Strings unless you know the origin of each, since a String that is built-up in some way (such as the `new String("A")` in Eli's comment or the `.toString()` used here) is not the same *reference* even if the two do use the same underlying character array.

```
class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String oneA = "A";
    String twoA = "A";
    String three = new StringBuilder().append('A').toString();

    // We expect constant literals to be ==
    System.out.print("A == A -> ");
    System.out.println("A" == "A");

    // Variables assigned the same literal are also ==
    System.out.print("oneA == twoA -> ");
    System.out.println(oneA == twoA);

    // but a built-up String var is not == to the "literal" var.
    System.out.print("oneA == three -> ");
    System.out.println(oneA == three);

    // If we intern() them they are again ==
    System.out.print("oneA.intern() == three.intern() -> ");
    System.out.println(oneA.intern() == three.intern());

    // and of course, .equals() is always safe.
    System.out.print("oneA .equals three -> ");
    System.out.println(oneA.equals(three));
  }
}
```

The output from this (run on https://repl.it/languages/java) is:

```
A == A -> true
oneA == twoA -> true
oneA == three -> false
oneA.intern() == three.intern() -> true
oneA .equals three -> true
```

You can safely use `string1.equals(string2)` or `string1.intern() == string2.intern()`