# Why the == operation fails with ""+ in string java

Tags: java, string

```
String s1 = "java";

String s2 = "java";

System.out.println(s1==s2);  //true
System.out.println(""+s1==s2); //false
```

**why the output is so?**

in the second case only added "" quotes.

Comment: you can't say "solved" when the question is "why the output". If you would've said: "How to prinln true regardless of adding `""+`" then yes, you solved the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning

Comment: you are getting confused with references comparison and values comparisons and last but not least watch out to the `String pool`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `==` compares references of two string objects which will be different for the two cases above.
- **.equals()** compares the value of the 2 string objects
- for String objects the `String pool` will save some memory by regrouping to the same place in memory different String objects with the same value.

**Look at the following code to understand how it works:**

```
String s1 = "java";//first string
String s2 = "java";//thanks to string pool the s2 is actually using the same memory location as s1 (saving space for same value string objects)

System.out.println(s1==s2);  //true ref comparison equals thanks to string pool intervention
System.out.println(""+s1==s2); //false (the resulting string of ""+s1 is stored in a different place in memory than s4
System.out.println(""+(s1==s2));//true due to string pool
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));  //true -> value comparison
System.out.println(s2.equals(""+s1)); //true -> value comparison


String s3 = new String("java");//this construction does not let the string pool intervene
String s4 = new String("java");//2 different memory locations for those 2 objects

System.out.println(s3==s4);  //false no string pool intervention -> 2 different memory locations
System.out.println(""+s3==s4); //false false (the resulting string of ""+s3 is stored in a different place in memory than s4
System.out.println(""+(s3==s4));//false no string pool intervention -> 2 different memory locations
System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));  //true -> value comparison
System.out.println(s4.equals(""+s3)); //true -> value comparison
```