# How exactly does shallow copy on Case Classes work in Scala?

Tags: scala, case-class, shallow-copy

I'm a beginner in Scala, and I'm confused on how shallow copy works for case class `var`.
I tried an example similar to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52967063/11680744.
This is my code.

```
case class Entity(eType: String, var unique : Boolean)

val entity = Entity("number", true)
val entity2 = entity.copy()
entity2.unique = false

println(entity)
println(entity2)
```

The Output is:

```
Entity(number,true)
Entity(number,false)
```

Why is the change in `entity2` not reflected in `entity`?

Comment: `var` in a **case class** is a bad practice. And if you want mutations to one copy to be reflected on the other copy, you are not only defeating the purpose of such _(copy)_ but that will bring you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks. But, I'm aware that it is a bad usage. Tried it just to understand the working of copy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to the one in the linked **question** (as opposed to the answer), with

```
 entity2.unique = false
```

corresponding to

```
 p1.firstname = "raghu"
```

In the answer

```
 a1.l.remove(1)
```

doesn't reassign `a1.l`, so `a1.l` and `a2.l` remain pointing at the same `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: It may be useful to mention that at the end `copy` is not really _copying_ the class. It just calls the constructor to create a new instance and uses the values of the current instance as the defaults of the arguments.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Calling the constructor with the current instance values as default arguments. Isn't it the way an _actual copy_ of an object is generally created?

Comment: @Vjay_Rav not necessary, you may just copy the memory occupied by one object to another object, that way the inner state may be preserved. That is a somewhat common assumption.