# comparing concatinated strings and normal strings

Tags: java, string

when i am comparing a string that is concatinated and comparing the objects of the concatinated string and normal string its showing false. I thought that the Strig literal "kalyansreekar" is already present in String constant pool. can soomeone explain me why this is happening and also the implementation code of string concatination. Thank you.

```
String a="kalyan";
String b=a+"sreekar";
String c="kalyansreekar";
System.out.println(b==c);
```

"I expect the result to be true, but the actual output is false"

Answer (score 0):

Here b==c compares the reference of the string not the content of the string.
If you want to compare value of string then use b.equals(c) instead of b==c

Comment: i don't want to compare values. I thought both the references b and c will point to same string literal "kalyansreekar" string in constant pool and so the output should be true but its not.

Comment: @KalyanSreekarJhade well then you just tested it and saw it was not the case. Use `intern()` to make it so.

Comment: But that doesn't mean they're pointing to the same place in memory, they are separate objects.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` on `String` internally uses a `StringBuilder` that returns a new `String` *instance* (on Java <= 8) or uses [`invokedynamic`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280) (on Java >= 9).

Code constants like `"kaylan"`, `"sreekar"` and `"kalyansreekar"` are [interned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-java-string-interning) in the JVM String pool. If you *really* want to compare using references, then try:

```
String a="kalyan";
String b=a+"sreekar";
b=b.intern(); // Puts it in the String pool
String c="kalyansreekar";
System.out.println(b==c); // true
```

Comment: `+` on String doesn't use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn it does on my setup when I debug through it. What does it use on yours?

Comment: It uses `invokedynamic`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn interesting. I'll check on that and include a link if I find one.

Comment: It was changed in Java 9, with [JEP 280](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that makes sense: I'm still on Java 8 (and sometimes 7...) ;) I thought it might be used in some other JVM languages like Scala.