# Java String intern function result problem

Tags: java, string, intern

I'm learning Java now, and i read this question:[What is Java String interning? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-java-string-interning)
but i read other articles which provide some examples i don't understand:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str2 = new String("str") + new String("01");
        str2.intern();
        String str1 = "str01";
        System.out.println(str2 == str1);  //true

        String s4 = new String("1");
        s4.intern();
        String s5 = "1";
        System.out.println(s4 == s5);   //false

        String s = new StringBuilder("aa").append("bb").toString();
        String s2 = new StringBuilder("cc").toString();
        System.out.println(s.intern() == s);    //true
        System.out.println(s2.intern() == s2);  //false
    }
```

the result in Java 11( it should be same in Java 8) is :

```js
true
false
true
false
```

i don't know why results are different, i suppose it to be all true.
can anyone explains it?

Comment: `intern()` **returns** the interned string, so you need to assign it, e.g. `str2 = str2.intern();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what [`intern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) actually does (emphasis mine):

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. *Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool* and a reference to this String object is returned.

When this code is run:

```
str2.intern();
```

The string pool only contains `"str"` and `"01"`. `str2` is `"str01"`, which is not in the string pool, so the object that `str2` refers too is added to the string pool. Therefore, when the next line is reached, since `"str01"` is already in the pool, `str1` will refer to the same object as `str2`.

Note that the reason why `str2 == str1` is *not* because `intern` somehow changes which object `str2` refers to. It *doesn't* do anything to `str2`. Strings are immutable after all.

Now we can understand the first `false`. In the line:

```
String s4 = new String("1");
```

Because of the string literal `"1"`, `"1"` is added to the string pool. Note that the object that is added to the string pool is not the same as the object to which `s4` refers. Now you call `s4.intern()`, which does nothing to `s4`, and *returns the object that is in the string pool*. But you are ignoring the return value. This is why `s4 != s5`, and `s4.intern() == s5`.

The reason for `s2.intern() != s2` is much simpler - `s2` refers to a different object than `"cc"` in the string pool! `s2.intern()` is supposed to return the object in the string pool, so of course it is not the same object!