# Is there any pool system like String pool for List.of()

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following method:

```
private boolean isExist(String key) {
   return List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e").contains(key);
}
```

Does this create N number of `List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")` objects for N method executions? Or is there any kind of mechanism like string pool internally?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, but String objects do have pool and they are usually handled by JVM, you can read a bit more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-java-string-interning
EDIT: also your code snippet if invalid.

Comment: No, there is no pool for lists.

Comment: *FYI:* If you want to call `contains()` you should use `Set.of()`, not `List.of()`, for better lookup performance.

Comment: Maybe this list should be `final static`if you are worrying about memory usage

Comment: @jhamon Thanks. Yes, we can use `final static`. I am interested to know the JVM behavior for this `List.of()`.

Answer (score 2):

"a", "b", "c", "d", "e" will be moved to the string pool unless they are already there. Next time you are accessing any of them (for example, "a"), no objects will be created, just pulled from the pool.

What you are asking is irrelevant to the pool, though. It largely depends on the implementation of `List` being returned. It could always return a new list (which is highly likely) or extract it from an internal cache (which is improbable since it's not effective for data structures of arbitrary size - imagine how expensive a lookup in that kind of cache would be).

Java 9's implementation looks like

```
static <E> List<E> of(E e1) {
    return new List12(e1);
}

static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2) {
    return new List12(e1, e2);
}

static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3) {
    return new ListN(new Object[]{e1, e2, e3});
}
```

with some nice micro-optimisations

```
@SafeVarargs
static <E> List<E> of(E... elements) {
    switch(elements.length) {
    case 0:
        return ImmutableCollections.emptyList();
    case 1:
        return new List12(elements[0]);
    case 2:
        return new List12(elements[0], elements[1]);
    default:
        return new ListN(elements);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user85421 I don't have java 9 at hand, but I assumed so, thanks