# Scala interning: how does different initialisation affect comparison?

Tags: string, scala

I am new to Scala but I know Java. Thus, as far as I understand, the difference is that `==` in Scala acts as `.equals` in Java, which means we are looking for the value; and `eq` in Scala acts as `==` in Java, which means we are looking for the reference address and not value.

However, after running the code below:

```
    val greet_one_v1 = "Hello"
    val greet_two_v1 = "Hello"
    println(
            (greet_one_v1 == greet_two_v1),
            (greet_one_v1 eq greet_two_v1)
    )


    val greet_one_v2 = new String("Hello")
    val greet_two_v2 = new String("Hello")
    println(
            (greet_one_v2 == greet_two_v2),
            (greet_one_v2 eq greet_two_v2)
    )
```

I get the following output:

```
(true,true)
(true,false)
```

My theory is that the initialisation of these strings differs. Hence, how is `val greet_one_v1 = "Hello"` different from `val greet_one_v2 = new String("Hello")`? Or, if my theory is incorrect, why do I have different outputs?

Comment: Probably due [**String Intering**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-java-string-interning). The compiler simple rewrites your original code, so both strings are actually the same one.

Comment: typo, luis. you meant "interning".

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez so, does Scala apply interning automatically on all objects, and the only way to disable it is to initiate through "new String("")"?

Comment: JVM does it automatically, not Scala, and only on `String` passed as literals.

Comment: You get the same result in Java if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly answered by Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, the answer lies in [String Interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-java-string-interning) which is part of what JVM (Java Virtual Machine) does automatically. To initiate a new String it needs to be initiated explicitly like in my example above; otherwise, Java will allocate the same memory for same values for optimisation reasons.