# can I use WeakHashMap instead of HashMap

Tags: java

I was going through `WeakHashMap` in Java. And what I  have understood is `WeakHashMap` is exactly as `HashMap` except its key references are `WeakReference`. That means key references are eligible for `gc`, and when it is garbaged, its entry will be removed from the map. This is not available in `HashMap`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I have one question over here.

Now in future If I get a requirement that I have to use Map for putting key and value,can I go forward with `WeakHashMap`? Or do I need to consider any scenario where `WeakHashMap` wont be fit only `HashMap` will fit?

Comment: Do you understand what WeakReference means? And when exactly it will become eligible for GC? You cannot just replace all HashMaps with WeakHashMaps... They both have different behaviors...

Comment: See also [When would you use a WeakHashMap or a WeakReference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154724/when-would-you-use-a-weakhashmap-or-a-weakreference) and [What is a WeakHashMap and when to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511279/what-is-a-weakhashmap-and-when-to-use-it)

Answer (score 2):

You do need to consider the context to decide whether it is correct / safe to use a WeakHashMap.

Here's an example where a WeakHashMap would not work (pseudo-code)

```
Map<Name, Details> map = ...
do for ever:
    name = get name from user
    if lookup:
        details = map.get(name)
        display details
    else if create:
        details = get details from user
        map.add(name, details)
```

With a WeakHashMap, there is a risk that entries will drop out of the table, and the user's lookups will fail.  With a HashMap, there is no risk.

---

There is also the issue that WeakReference and anything built on it is more expensive than ordinary references.  They use more space and time.  More significantly, the Reference classes incur overheads each time the GC encounters them, which can increase GC pause times.

However, the issue of runtime overheads should *normally* be secondary to the correctness issue.

- If you use a `HashMap` when you should be using a `WeakHashMap`, then you are liable to run into problems with your heap filling up.  And that has performance issues too.
- If you use `WeakHashMap` where you should be using a `HashMap`, you may loose information.

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where a [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) won't replace a HashMap, for example:

1. When calling an API where an argument type is the concrete type `HashMap<K, V>` rather than the interface type `Map<K, V>`.
2. When your code assumes nothing else is changing the map out from under it. The garbage collector can remove weak keys at any time, causing the WeakHashMap methods to act as if entries were removed just then. So e.g. if you put the map size into a variable, the actual map may be smaller than that when you enumerate it. (See the JavaDoc for examples.) It's risky to pass a WeakHashMap to code that may not be prepared for such changes. Synchronizing won't help this.
3. When you don't want the extra overhead in space and time.

I recommend using a WeakHashMap only when you need to (e.g. a listener registry) and only when all the code that touches it is explicitly prepared for disappearing entries.