# Is there a "clean" way to automatically un-register a listener in Java?

Tags: java, listener

I believe I've seen variants of this question, but no "definitive answer". In the code below, I understand that SomeEventManager holds a reference to someImplClassTwo.myEventListenerA and someImplClassTwo.myEventListenerB, and that this does not allow for someImplClassTwo to be garbage collected, and this results in the output generated the second time someEventManager.notifyListeners() is invoked.

But, I'd really like for users of SomeImplClass not to have to know that there are listeners involved in the implementation, and that these listeners need to be manually un-registered (i.e., SomeImplClass.releaseListeners()) before releasing the SomeImplClass object.

Is there a clean/accepted way of doing this?

p.s. I've already played with finalize(), just for fun, and confirmed that GC is not even attempted in this case, for either instance of SomeImplClass. So, that seems to be a non-starter as a potential solution.

Test Driver

```
public class TestDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeEventManager someEventManager = SomeEventManager.getInstance();
        SomeImplClass    someImplClassOne = new SomeImplClass("One");
        SomeImplClass    someImplClassTwo = new SomeImplClass("Two");

        someEventManager.notifyListeners();

        someImplClassOne.releaseListeners();
        someImplClassOne = null;
        someImplClassTwo = null;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
        someEventManager.notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Event Interface

```
public interface SomeEventListener {
    public void handleSomeEvent();
}
```

Event Manager

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeEventManager {
    private static SomeEventManager        eventManager = null;
    private        List<SomeEventListener> listeners    = null;

    private SomeEventManager() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<SomeEventListener>();
    }

    public static SomeEventManager getInstance() {
        if (eventManager == null) {
            eventManager = new SomeEventManager();
        }
        return eventManager;
    }

    public void addListener(SomeEventListener listener) {
        if (!listeners.contains(listener)) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }
    }

    public void removeListener(SomeEventListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void notifyListeners() {
        for(SomeEventListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.handleSomeEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

Event Listener Implementation

```
public class SomeImplClass {
    private InnerEventListener myEventListenerA = null;
    private InnerEventListener myEventListenerB = null;
    private String             id               = null;

    public SomeImplClass(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        myEventListenerA = new InnerEventListener(id + "_A");
        myEventListenerB = new InnerEventListener(id + "_B");
    }

    public void releaseListeners() {
        myEventListenerA.unregisterListener();
        myEventListenerB.unregisterListener();
    }

    private class InnerEventListener implements SomeEventListener {
        private SomeEventManager someEventManager = null;
        private String           id               = null;

        public InnerEventListener(String id) {
            someEventManager = SomeEventManager.getInstance();
            this.id          = id;
            registerListener();
        }

        public void registerListener() {
            someEventManager.addListener(this);
        }

        public void unregisterListener() {
            someEventManager.removeListener(this);
        }

        public void handleSomeEvent() {
            System.out.println("InnerEventListener->" + id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [`WeakHashMap`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511279/what-is-a-weakhashmap-and-when-to-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we use is to have the listener automatically unregister itself if it gets called and the thing it's updating has been collected.

It looks a bit like this:

```
private static class InnerEventListener implements SomeEventListener {
    private final WeakReference<ThingToUpdate> thingRef;

    public InnerEventListener(ThingToUpdate thing) {
        thingRef = new WeakReference<>(thing);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleSomeEvent(SomeEvent event) {
        ThingToUpdate thing = thingRef.get();
        if (thing != null) {
            thing.updateSomehow();
        } else {
            ((SomeEventedThing) event.getSource())
                .removeSomeEventListener(this);
        }
    }
}

//...

SomeEventedThing eventedThing;
ThingToUpdate thingToUpdate;

//...

eventedThing.addListener(new InnerEventListener(thingToUpdate));
```

I wouldn't say it's a perfect solution because the listener sticks around until it gets an event, and it's still somewhat dependent on garbage collection. We've been trying to replace it with explicit removal where possible, usually on addNotify/removeNotify on GUI components.

Comment: I'm taking a similar route...for now. Your approach assumes ThingToUpdate's lifecycle doesn't extend beyond listener's, so it's specific to that scenario.

My approach holds the listener itself as a weak reference (also implementation specific?), but works for my need. But, I cannot have listeners be an inner class, as the outer class holds a strong reference, and the inner an implicit reference (assumed strong?) to the outer...preventing either from being garbage collected.

Maybe would be nice (simpler?) if Java used a weak reference for the inner class' reference to the outer?