# Java7 WeakHashMap isEmpty() seems wrong

Tags: java, weakhashmap

I'm trying to use Java7's WeakHashMap and I found its isEmpty() method give me wrong results.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Map<String, Boolean> map = new WeakHashMap<>();

        String b = new String("B");
        map.put(b, true);
        b = null;

        System.gc();
        System.out.println(map.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(map.keySet().isEmpty());
        System.out.println(map);
    }

}
```

The actual result:

false

true

{}

That is to say,

map.isEmpty() and map.keySet().isEmpty() is not consistent. 
Can someone help me to understand it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: From Java 8 API doc for the class: 
"Because the garbage collector may discard keys at any time, a WeakHashMap may behave as though an unknown thread is silently removing entries." and "..it is possible for the size method to return smaller values over time, for the isEmpty method to return false and then true..", so I see no reason for worry.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511279/what-is-a-weakhashmap-and-when-to-use-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WeakHashMap::isEmpty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html#isEmpty()) says:

> ...This result is a snapshot, and may not reflect unprocessed entries
>   that will be removed before next attempted access because they are no
>   longer referenced.

So you would expect that `isEmpty()` returns the correct value after GC **and** after access. This code demonstrates this:

```
public class Scratch1 {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Map<String, Boolean> map = new WeakHashMap<>();

        String b = new String("B");
        map.put(b, true);
        b = null;

        System.gc();

        // map not internally accessed at this point
        System.out.println(map.isEmpty());

        // let's access the Map's internals (and hopefully coerce
        // it into removing no-longer-referenced keys)
        System.out.println(map.keySet()
                              .isEmpty());

        // map HAS now been accessed
        System.out.println(map.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

Yields:

```
false
true
true
```

Answer (score 7):

You should read the javadoc of [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html):

> The behavior of the `WeakHashMap` class depends in part upon the actions of the garbage collector, so several familiar (though not required) `Map` invariants do not hold for this class. Because the garbage collector may discard keys at any time, a `WeakHashMap` may behave as though an unknown thread is silently removing entries. In particular, even if you synchronize on a `WeakHashMap` instance and invoke none of its mutator methods, **it is possible for the `size` method to return smaller values over time, for the `isEmpty` method to return `false` and then `true`,** for the `containsKey` method to return `true` and later `false` for a given key, for the `get` method to return a value for a given key but later return `null`, for the `put` method to return `null` and the `remove` method to return `false` for a key that previously appeared to be in the map, and for successive examinations of the key set, the value collection, and the entry set to yield successively smaller numbers of elements.

The short of all that is the the effects you've seen are entirely valid.

Comment: @EricDuminil As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405864/java7-weakhashmap-isempty-seems-wrong/55405951?noredirect=1#comment97532450_55405864) by Leonardo Alves Machado: Check [What is a WeakHashMap and when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5511279/5221149)