# SetIcon in CellRenderer causing lag

Tags: java, list, swing, listcellrenderer

I'm using a custom listcellrenderer with a list and setting both a title and an image but it's really laggy because the image keeps loading everytime i scroll. Is there any way i can fix this ?
Here is my code:

```
 @Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Movie> list, Movie value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    
        this.titleHolder.setText(value.getTitle());
        this.imageHolder.setIcon(new ImageIcon(value.getPoster()));
        
    
    return this;

}
```

I basically want the image to stop loading everytime i scroll through the list because it's causing the app to lag really heavly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not cache the `ImageIcon` e.g. in a `Map<String, Icon>`?

Comment: How exactly can i do that ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will be to create some sort cache as already mentioned by weisj in comment section.

Implement the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method of `Movie` class if you have not done already.

Now create your cache:

```
private Map<Movie,ImageIcon> moviePostersCache = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, inside `getListCellRendererComponent`:

```
@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Movie> list, Movie value, int index,
        boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    this.titleHolder.setText(value.getTitle());
    
    
    if (!moviePostersCache.containsKey(value))
        moviePostersCache.put(value, new ImageIcon(value.getPoster()));
    
    this.imageHolder.setIcon(moviePostersCache.get(value));
    return this;
}
```

And the posters will be on memory. After first render they will not be "reloaded" - `Movie#getPoster` will not be called.

Now, if there a lot of movies that come and go to the gui, consider [using a weak hash map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511279/what-is-a-weakhashmap-and-when-to-use-it).

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the icons based on `Movie#getTitle` (which I assume is of type `String`.

```java
private Map<String, Icon> iconCache = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Movie> list, Movie value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    this.titleHolder.setText(value.getTitle());
    this.imageHolder.setIcon(iconCache.computeIfAbsent(value.getPoster(), ImageIcon::new));
    return this;
}
```