# Why we are obliged to clear a PhantomReference manually?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, phantom-reference

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html):

> Unlike soft and weak references, phantom references are not automatically cleared by the garbage collector as they are enqueued. An object that is reachable via phantom references will remain so until all such references are cleared or themselves become unreachable.

Once put into ReferenceQueue, the phantom link's referent object is presumed to be "dead", it's inaccessible in any way by programmer's code. So why JVM waits for a manual `clear()`? For weak refs it doesn't.

Comment: This has changed since Java 9, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) and [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-notes-3745703.html#JDK-8071507). Phantom references are now cleared like soft and weak references, see also the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41987600/9014097).

Answer (score 2):

In [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41987600/9014097) to a related question about the behavior of a `PhantomReference` when the queue is given as `null`, Holger says this:

> *"The question, even harder to answer, is why a `PhantomReference` isn’t automatically cleared. The documentation only says that a phantom reachable object will remain so, which is the consequence of not being cleared, but doesn’t explain why this has any relevance.*
>
> *This question has been [brought up on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7048767/2711488), but the answer isn’t really satisfying. It says “to allow performing cleanup before an object is garbage collected”, which might even match the mindset of whoever made that design decision, but since the cleanup code can’t access the object, it has no relevance whether it is executed before or after the object is reclaimed. As said above, since this rule depends on the reachability of the `PhantomReference` object, which is subject to optimizing code transformations, it might be even the case that the object is reclaimed together with the `PhantomReference` instance before the cleanup code completes, without anyone noticing.*
>
> *I also found a [similar question on the HotSpot developer mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-dev/2013-May/007384.html) back in 2013 which also lacks an answer.*
>
> *There is the enhancement request [JDK-8071507](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071507) to change that behavior and clear `PhantomReferences` just like the others, which has the status “fixed” for Java 9, and indeed, the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) now state that they are cleared like any other reference."*

---

In summary:

- The original design decision to not clear the reference was questionable.
- The behavior has changed, as of Java 9.

However you asked your question like this:

> So why JVM waits for a manual `clear()`?

Strictly speaking, the JVM waits for *either* a manual clear, *or* for the `PhantomReference` itself to become unreachable.  (As Holger said above.)

So it is not quite as bad (in Java 8 and earlier) as your question would imply.