# Why does PhantomReference.get() always return null?

Tags: java, reference, phantom-reference

I know the different kinds of references, and reachability, and how the garbage collector works in general - I have also used the different types of `Reference`s in some of my personal projects. However, there is one design choice I don't understand: Why the `get`  method of `PhantomReference`s always returns `null`.

`PhantomReference`s are mostly (only?) used for cleanup actions after the object has "died". So, the usual answer to my question is "to ensure that the object can't get (strongly) reachable again after the cleanup has started" - or, as [the documentation of PhantomReference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) puts it:

> In order to ensure that a reclaimable object remains so, the referent of a phantom reference may not be retrieved: The get method of a phantom reference always returns null.

But as far as I understand, "ensuring that a reclaimable object remains so" doesn't imply that `get()` must always return `null`: As long as a phantom reference isn't cleared, its referent isn't reclaimable and also won't be enqueued, and thus the cleanup action won't have been started - meaning that `get()` could "safely" give access to the referent. It only becomes reclaimable if the reference is cleared, so `get()` would from then on return `null` either way. There's also no possibility of race conditions (example: two PhantomRefs to one object; one gets cleared and enqueued, then the object is made accessible again through the other's `get` method), because the documentation states that all clearing happens atomically (emphasis mine):

> At that time it will **atomically** clear **all** phantom references to that object and all phantom references to any other phantom-reachable objects from which that object is reachable.

---

Because the question came up in comments: I'm asking this not because I have a concrete problem for which I think this would be the solution. Instead, I need to describe the various `Reference` types in my Master's thesis, where they are relevant, and I want to describe them correctly - including the reasoning behind the design choices.

However, I can still think of a concrete situation which would explicitly not be covered by using a `WeakReference`:

Suppose you were writing a library which provided some service to its users. Let's assume the library wants to ensure that only one instance of this service exists at a time - that it is a "singleton", so to speak - so let's call the class `PublicSingletonService`. However, let's assume the service needs many resources to exist - so, the library wants to throw it away once it's not needed anymore, and recreate it once it's needed again. I think this is a reasonable scenario.

So, the library holds a `WeakReference` to its singleton, and uses a `ReferenceQueue` to detect if the singleton is not needed anymore and to clean up. When the user requests the service, the library calls `get()` on the `WeakReference`, and if the result is non-`null`, returns that, and if it is `null`, it (re-)creates the service.

But now, the application using that library does the following:

1. It requests the service singleton
2. It creates an object (the "holder"), which refers to the service singleton and has a finalizer which will make the object (and thus the service singleton) reachable again.
3. It clears all remaining references to the service singleton and the holder, such that it is only weakly reachable (through the library's weak reference)
4. It uses much memory (or calls `System.gc()`, such that the GC clears the weak ref and starts the holder's finalization
5. The following three things happen in any order:

- the holder's finalizer "resurrects" the service singleton
- The library cleans up after the singleton
- The application requests another service singleton - this will be newly created.
  Now, the application has two singleton instances, despite the library not having any problematic finalizers!

The library could partially guard against this by keeping a `PhantomReference` in addition to the `WeakReference`, and only cleaning up or creating a second instance if the `PhantomReference` is cleared. However, this has a problem: If the `WeakReference` is cleared, but the `PhantomReference` is not, and the application asks the library to give it an instance of the service, the library can neither access the old instance nor create a new one.

If `PhantomReference.get()` did not always return `null`, this would be solvable: just let the library use a `PhantomReference` instead of a `WeakReference`, and use `PhantomReference.get()`.

Here is an example program demonstrating this:

```java
package weirdjava;

import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import weirdjava.StronglyReachableAfterWeakReferenceCleared.Library.PublicSingletonService;

public class StronglyReachableAfterWeakReferenceCleared
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Application.run();
    }

    public static class Application
    {
        public static void run() throws InterruptedException
        {
            // Application code initializes the library
            Library library = new Library();
            // "Library" creates the singleton of the public service and tries to detect once it is _definitely_ unreachable.
            PublicSingletonService singleton = library.getSingleton();

            // The application code then does weird stuff with the singleton (maliciously, bad programming, or convoluted interactions):
            // make holder
            ApplicationHolder holder = new ApplicationHolder(singleton);
            // clear the last remaining strong ref to the singleton
            singleton = null;
            // make sure the libraries' weakref is actually cleared - simulates the application using much memory.
            System.gc();

            // The "library" tries to detect whether the object was cleared, and clean up if it is.
            // In this example, we made sure that it is.
            library.doCleanupIfNecessary();

            // The application asks the library for the singleton again - because it has been cleared, the library recreates the singleton.
            PublicSingletonService secondSingleton = library.getSingleton();

            // Now, the application magically resurrects the first singleton
            PublicSingletonService resurrectedSingleton = holder.getReferent();
            if(resurrectedSingleton == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("example failed");

            System.out.println("Resurrection successful! resurrected: " + resurrectedSingleton);

            // At this point, the weak references to the object have been cleared,
            // but the object is still strongly reachable -
            // and that without the libraries' class having any finalizer.
            System.out.println("Application now has two singletons: " + resurrectedSingleton + ", " + secondSingleton);
        }
        private static class ApplicationHolder
        {
            private final Semaphore     referrerFinalizationComplete;
            private FinalizableReferrer referrerAfterFinalization;

            public ApplicationHolder(PublicSingletonService referent)
            {
                referrerFinalizationComplete = new Semaphore(0);
                // explicitly don't keep a reference to this, to let it be able to be reclaimed
                new FinalizableReferrer(this, referent);
            }

            public PublicSingletonService getReferent() throws InterruptedException
            {
                referrerFinalizationComplete.acquire();
                return referrerAfterFinalization.getReferent();
            }

            private static class FinalizableReferrer
            {
                private final ApplicationHolder referrer;
                private final PublicSingletonService    referent;

                public FinalizableReferrer(ApplicationHolder referrer, PublicSingletonService referent)
                {
                    this.referrer = referrer;
                    this.referent = referent;
                }

                @Override
                protected void finalize()
                {
                    System.out.println("Finalizer making referent reachable again");
                    referrer.referrerAfterFinalization = this;
                    referrer.referrerFinalizationComplete.release();
                }

                public PublicSingletonService getReferent()
                {
                    return referent;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Library
    {
        // just for demonstration; in reality, this would have to be thread-safe and whatnot
        private int instanceCounter = 0;

        private final ReferenceQueue<PublicSingletonService>    refqueue;
        private WeakReference<PublicSingletonService>       publicSingletonObjectRef;

        public Library()
        {
            this.refqueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
        }

        public void doCleanupIfNecessary() throws InterruptedException
        {
            // In practice, this would be poll(), not remove() - however, in this example,
            // even though we called System.gc() the enqueueing doesn't happen fast enough.
            Reference<? extends PublicSingletonService> poll = refqueue.remove();
            if(poll != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Reference to referent was cleared; weakRef.get() is " + publicSingletonObjectRef.get()); // is null
                // The library cleans up what it needs to clean up
                System.out.println("Library \"cleans up\"");
            } else
                // In practice, the library would do nothing here.
                throw new IllegalStateException("example failed");
        }

        public PublicSingletonService getSingleton()
        {
            if(publicSingletonObjectRef != null)
            {
                // This is the call to get() which would not be possible with a phantom reference
                PublicSingletonService previousInstance = publicSingletonObjectRef.get();
                if(previousInstance != null)
                    return previousInstance;
            }

            PublicSingletonService publicSingletonObjectInstance = new PublicSingletonService("Instance #" + instanceCounter ++);
            publicSingletonObjectRef = new WeakReference<>(publicSingletonObjectInstance, refqueue);
            return publicSingletonObjectInstance;
        }

        public static class PublicSingletonService
        {
            private final String value;

            public PublicSingletonService(String value)
            {
                this.value = value;
                System.out.println("Creating singleton object: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The (language-level) answer to your example situation isn't screwing with phantom references. The answer is getting rid of finalizers. They were a mistake, they are deprecated, and the `finalize` method will be removed in a future Java version.

Comment: Yes, I that would definitely be the ideal solution - but in an ideal world where finalizers don't exist, we wouldn't need PhantomRefs anyway, right? Then, they would be equivalent to WeakRefs (except not supporting get), or did I miss something?

Comment: So, there would be no reason for the language designers to introduce PhantomRefs __except__ to work around finalizers. Or is the intention here that if the finalizer doesn't make the object reachable, no one can?

Comment: Probably to enable more efficient collection strategies, and because getting the referent isn't useful for the job PhantomReference was designed for. PhantomReference is designed to enable post-mortem cleanup, not to do anything with the referent itself.

Comment: How does this enable more efficient collection strategies? And why can't WeakReferences be used for post-mortem cleanup without the presence of finalizers? In the presence of finalizers, sure, WeakRefs aren't enough to ensure the object has "died" - but then my example shows that get() on PhantomRefs would have a sensible use.

Comment: It seems to me the existence of PhantomRefs is justified by saying "we need to handle the presence of finalizers, so WeakRef isn't enough for cleanups", but get() working on PhantomRefs is regarded as unjustified by saying that "we don't need to handle the presence of finalizers because are deprecated, so just use a WeakRef" - which seems paradoxical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to the Java 20 API. But in this case, it’s useful to know the history.

Have a look at [Java 8’s `PhantomReference` documentation from 2022](https://web.archive.org/web/20221016015442/https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html)

> Unlike soft and weak references, phantom references are not automatically cleared by the garbage collector as they are enqueued. An object that is reachable via phantom references will remain so until all such references are cleared or themselves become unreachable.

Don’t ask why keeping an object phantom reachable ever was a goal. [That has](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7048767/2711488) [been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57439236/2711488) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396051/phantomreference-with-null-queue/41987600#41987600:%7E:text=The%20question%2C%20even,is%20why%20a%20PhantomReference%20isn%E2%80%99t%20automatically%20cleared.) and never got a satisfying answer. That’s part of the reason why this rule has been removed in Java 9 and as it seems, [also in the latest Java 8 updates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html).

But when an enqueued `PhantomReference` is not cleared, it’s obviously needed to prevent the retrieval via the `get()` method, to prevent resurrection of reclaimable objects. Granted, deep reflection still worked back in the days, which is another indicator that this part of the API wasn’t well thought.

---

The current state of affairs is that phantom reference are cleared when enqueued and hence, nothing prevents the reclamation of the object while the post-mortem cleanup is running.

So, the original problem is gone. Allowing `get()` to return the referent would not affect the way, garbage collection works. It would become possible to retrieve the object while finalization is in progress, but this would only be a semantic problem, but not affect the logic of phantom references, as they are only enqueued when the object became unreachable (again) after finalization completed.

However, there is no reason to change the contract. Getting the object back is not necessary for the purpose of phantom references. That’s what weak references are for and since finalization [has been marked “deprecated, for removal”](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()), any problems related to finalization will vanish anyway.

---

It’s true that while finalization still exists, the scenario of resurrection exist when using weak references. However, if someone tries that hard to break your program, nothing will stop them anyway. Don’t let such people contribute to your code base. Java’s language mechanisms are not real security measures. They make it harder to write bad code, but can’t prevent people from deliberately breaking things.

That said, the entire idea to use garbage collection to release non-memory resources in the way you described, is flawed. There is no guaranty about when or whether at all the object will get collected, hence in your scenario this cleanup feature is not worth the development effort. But in the worst case, it will [break horribly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488).

Answer (score -1):

If `.get()` worked, you could simply do:

```
someField = phantomRef.get();
```

And all of a sudden the object that was in the process of being collected, now no longer collectable. After all, you assigned it to a field - it is reachable again. If it is collected soon after you have a field referencing a garbage collected object and that's one of those 100% most definitely cannot possibly ever happen ever ever ever red line you can't cross in JVM feature designs.

If it's *not* collected, i.e. that act 'cancels' the garbage collection, you have 2 problems:

1. Whatever process 'scanned' to figure out the object is collectable needs to re-scan because it cannot know that the result of `.get()` was used to re-live the object. Thus, any call to `.get()` at any time by anything means the object needs to be re-scanned. At which point... allow all phantom refs to do it again? Then we'd have an endless loop.
2. Alternatively, `.get()` needs to flag the JVM to run this thread in some sort of 'slow bookkeeping mode' where any `.get()` calls are tracked just to check if you are reliving them. Also, even if you don't assign it to any field, as long as whatever method called `get` hasn't completed, it's still a live object.

None of this is in any way practical. Returning `null` on `.get()` and specifying that this is what happens to phantom refs solves all problems.

Comment: Doesn't the same argument of practicality apply to the get method of any Reference? For example, if get is called on any weak reference, "whatever process which scanned to figure out the object is weakly reachable needs to rescan" analogously. Also, yes, if an application repeatedly calls get on a PhantomReference to make the referent strongly reachable again, we would have an "endless loop" - basically, the object would never be thrown away. But if the application does make a previously phantom reachable object reachable again, this behaviour is intended by the application (or a memory leak).

Comment: Reformulating the second part in other words: It is not a bad thing that get on a PhantomReference makes the object strongly reachable again - because that's precisely what the semantics of that method would be. It is up to the application (or, rather, its programmer) to decide whether this is intended or not.

Comment: a WeakRef hasn't hit the phase of 'okay it is _definitely_ going to be collected now' quite yet. There needs to be a time where the GC system says: I'm not going to consider this object as ever possibly being live again from here on out. If you want to be capable of re-living it, just use a WeakRef. That's what it is for.

Comment: You've sort of made your own argument here - 'hey, being able to deref the object that is about to get collected can be useful and if the app wants to re-live it, it should be able to'. Note that a WeakRef does not in any way imply an object has been selected for GCing. It simply implies the existence of the WeakRef has no effect on GCing it (i.e. its existence doesn't prevent the referent from being collected).

Comment: The docs spell this out: PhantomRefs can refer to things _even if_ they have been marked as 'reclaimable'. The JVM does not have a system to remove that mark (or rather, it doesn't want to, as that would make the GC system orders of magnitude more complicated), so it __must remain reclaimable__. Letting you get the object ref would mean it'd have to be turned un-reclaimable. No can do. And there's no need to build it for some exotic use cases, because those use cases can simply use WeakRef instead.

Comment: The one time where this may come up is that you _specifically_ want the ability to get a ping that an object is marked as reclaimable, and that you want to now check that object for some stats and have the option to go: "NO! WAIT! DO NOT DO THAT!". The JVM does not offer such a mechanism, refqueues aren't designed for you to have such an ability, and giving it to you would be performance-wise disastrous.

Comment: Perhaps we are talking past each other. In that case I suggest you edit this question, or probably ask a new one, and take a step back. You have a problem X (which you did not state) and you went: I know! I'll use PhantomRefs so I can fix my problem X! Oh, wait, phantomrefs always return `null`, that's weird. Let me ask an SO question about this. The better option is to just state X and ask how to solve it. Because that 'I know! PhantomReference!' - that was wrong.

Comment: The phase "the object is definitely collectable now" starts _after_ the PhantomRefs are cleared (before that, finalizers can of course make the object reachable again). I don't see a reason in your argument why the application shouldn't be allowed to get() the object before this point is reached. Also, a WeakRef being cleared kind of does imply that the GC is involved with that object - not that it's about to reclaim the object, sure, but that finalizers are run. Also, I do see a use case not covered by WeakRefs - I'll edit the question to include it.

Comment: As a side note: The assumption that I have a problem X, for which I thought that PhantomRefs are the solution, is incorrect; I stumbled upon this while writing my Master's thesis, where the various Reference types are relevant. So, I want to describe them correctly, including the reasoning behind the design choices. Moreover, I'm just genuinely interested in the reasoning behind this - even without having a concrete problem for which I think this is the answer.

Comment: SO isn't the right place to ask 'what was the reasoning' - you'd have to ask the designers and scour the relevant mailing lists. However, from what I recall from those mailing lists, this is the reason. Im very very short SO is not the place to hold a debate about the intelligence of the choices that were made. There are mailing lists for that run by the OpenJDK project.

Comment: If it's specifically about 'sooo, if I have a PhantomRef and the object hasn't yet reached the phase, why can't `.get()` returns the value until we get to that phase?' - eh, OpenJDK tends to design conservatively: If the use cases that the PhantomRef feature are designed for do not appear to need it, why offer it? OpenJDK has to support it __forever__ if they make it work that way. This is simpler to support. Sometimes there isn't a complicated scheme behind it all. Just 'this is simpler and offering it doesn't add any meaningful usecases we can think of right now, so.. let's not'.

Comment: I have now added an example where a WeakRef does not solve the problem, but a PhantomRef with get() does. I guess I just don't understand the asymmetry between the different refs - why get is provided on some, but not on others. I don't see why implementing get on one of the types would be harder than on others.

Comment: I just re-read the comment thread and noticed that you say that, effectively, implementing get on PhantomReferences "would make the GC system orders of magnitude more complicated". Can you edit your answer and elaborate on why this is the case? This would be an understandable, satisfying reason for me why get isn't implemented.

Comment: The answer already mentions why: Because it would require the GC system to have to support the notion that an object considered 'reclaimable' can still be referenced later on (and thus, should no longer be reclaimed). It's... obvious how that would make things very complicated. I wouldn't know how to explain that any further beyond writing it in all caps, I guess.

Comment: I don't think that part of your answer is correct. The documentation of java.lang.ref states: "Finally, an object is unreachable, and therefore eligible for reclamation, when it is not reachable in any of the above ways", where "any of the above ways" includes phantom references. So, an object is not reclaimable while phantom rechable - making your points about making a reclaimable object rechable again invalid. If I'm mistaken in this argumentation, please explain where that mistake is.

Comment: The garbage collector doesn’t mark objects as “reclaimable”. It does the opposite, it marks objects as “still reachable”. So when encountering special references, like weak, soft, or phantom, it has to decide whether to clear them (atomically, as the documentation says) or to treat them as reachable and traverse them. This even applied to the pre-Java 9 behavior where phantom references were not cleared. Despite the `get()` method always returned `null`, the garbage collector had to treat the non-cleared references like reachable and traverse them, reducing performance but staying unbreakable.