# How does HashMap in Java handle weak reference for keys and values?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, hashmap, out-of-memory, java-memory-model

I recently read a book about java memory modelling, it says : **HashMap use weak reference for keys and values(since they are all objects), so that hashmap can avoid out of memory issue when hasnmap stores more and more key value pairs.**

But the problem is : if keys and values are being GC during the rumtime, how can I get the key value pair by using **get** method in the hashmap?

for example,

```
String key=new String("GC");
String value=new String("GC");
hashmap.put(key,value);
```

and after a certain execution of the code, it has a chance that java GC the key and value, then what happen during:

```
hashmap.get(key)
```

since the key is no longer exist in hashmap ?

Comment: The book is wrong. A HashMap uses strong references. But there is a WeakHashMap, whose documentation explains how it works: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html

Comment: A related question about `WeakHashMap`, `WeakReference` and `SoftReference` is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154724/when-would-you-use-a-weakhashmap-or-a-weakreference).

Comment: Thanks, I think the book is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about WeakHashMap, it removes entries where keys are no longer referenced from outside map itself. And it only happens after GC cleared the key, like here:

```
    Map m = new WeakHashMap();
    m.put(new Object(), 1);       // key is referenced only by map itself
    System.out.println(m.size()); // prints 1
    System.gc();     
    Thread.sleep(1); // give GC some time
    System.out.println(m.size()); // prints 0
```

Comment: then after that, how can I retrieve this key-value pair?

Comment: you can't, it's removed by GC

Comment: Then whats the use case for weak reference or weakhashmap? I wont use any object which will suddenly point to null in the programme.....

Comment: from Effective Java Item 6: "Once you put an object reference into a cache, it’s easy to forget that it’s there and leave it in the cache long after it becomes irrelevant". Solution - WeakHashMap

Comment: See Thread source. It uses ThreadLocalMap with weak-reference keys,  when a ThreadLocal is not used anymore (no live reference), entires are automatically removed