# Weak association of one object with another in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, garbage-collection, java-8, weak-references

When I have come class

```
class MyClass1 {
    MyClass2 member;
}
```

ans it is garbage collected, then `member` also become eligible to garbage collection.

Can I simulate the same relation with `Map`?

So, I wish a map with weak references to keys. I.e. map itself should not prevent keys from garbage collection. And once key is garbage collected, then its associated value also become eligible to garbage collection.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Is this just [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)?

Comment: Yes, sounds like `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When would you use a WeakHashMap or a WeakReference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154724/when-would-you-use-a-weakhashmap-or-a-weakreference)

Comment: As long as the value doesn’t hold a reference to the key. The bigger question is *why*? What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely. Just use a `WeakHashMap`, which will use weak references to keys and remove entries when keys are garbage collected.